# Duplicate rows with multiple join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm using this code to join two table on contents table then group by user
when I join only analytics table the result is correct also the same wehn joining only reactions table
but both table is causing wrong result in sum and count

```
->where('users.type_id', 2)
->leftJoin('contents', 'users.id', '=', 'contents.instructor_id')
->leftJoin('analytics', 'contents.id', '=', 'analytics.content_id')
->leftJoin('reactions', 'contents.id', '=', 'reactions.content_id')

->selectRaw('
    users.id as id,
    concat(users.name, "-", users.last_name) as name,
    sum(analytics.total_watched) as sum_watched,
    count(analytics.id) as times_watched,
    sum(analytics.completed=1) as completed_video,

    sum(reactions.reaction_type="love") as love,
    sum(reactions.reaction_type="happy") as happy,
    sum(reactions.reaction_type="thinking") as thinking,
    sum(reactions.reaction_type="sad") as sad,
    sum(reactions.reaction_type="angry") as angry                    
')
->groupBy('users.id')
->limit(10)
->get();
```

Comment: instead of leftJoin use just join and see .

Comment: @Googlian thank you I've tried that but still the same result

Comment: Have you tried in raw SQL queries first ?

Comment: can you tell us what you intend to achieve versus what you're getting right now using that code

Comment: your inner table should be innerJoin and other you can use left

Comment: @alimbaronia I have an analytics table and reaction table with content_id so every content has analytics and reactions now I want to get the total of them by user as every content has a user

Comment: @Googlian no I'll try with raw sql, Now I've tried innerJoin in contents and leftJoin in analytics & reactions but the same result

Comment: Update your table structure and show the raw sql then we can assist, thank you

Comment: can you try inner join

Comment: that's the raw sql https://pastebin.com/R1FQjxfg the same result

Comment: Do you have Eloquent models set up for these tables? If so, do you have relationships set up between them?